# Prove : product of two ideals is also an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, lie-algebras, ideals

I'm new to Lie algebras.

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie Algebra with the bracket $[a,b]=ab-ba$.

and $I$ and $J$ are two Ideals, which  means that:

$$[I,\mathfrak{g}]\subset  I$$ and $$[J,\mathfrak{g}]\subset J.$$

So I have already proved that the subset $I+J$ is also an ideal,

but I have a problem when I tried to prove that the subset $IJ$ defined by

$$  IJ=\{z \in \mathfrak{g} \quad |\quad \exists (x,y)\in I\times J, \; z=xy\}$$

is also an ideal.
I tried this :
we need to prove that

$$ \forall y \in\mathfrak{g},\quad \forall  x\in IJ \quad [x,y] \in IJ  $$

let $x$ be in $IJ$ then $\exists (a,b)\in I\times J$ with $x=ab$

$$ [x,y]=[ab,y]=aby-yab=...=a[b,y]+[a,y]b$$

we know that $[b,y] \in J $ because $J$ is ideal then:  $$a[b,y]\in IJ$$
by the same way $$[a,y]b\in IJ$$
My problem  is that I can NOT prove that $a[b,y]+[a,y]b \in IJ$ cause nothing says that "$+$" is inner map in $IJ$.

Comment: you are right; Let $G$ be an Associative algebra , that means a vector space with a bi-linear map  
 $\times :\;G\times G \to G  $ that takes $(x,y)\to xy $
then we can associate to $G$ **another** bi-linear map that defined by the Lie bracket  $[,] :G\times G \to G$ $[x,y]:=xy-yx$ ,$G$ together with Lie bracket is a Lie algebra

Comment: In ring theory, the product of two ideals $I, J$ is defined as the set of elements of the form $\sum_ka_kb_$ with $a_k\in I, b_k\in J$. Probably this is meant here too, and you're done.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205019/prove-product-of-two-ideals-is-also-an-ideal).

Comment: In general the bracket in a Lie algebra is not of the form $[a,b]=ab-ba$ or some associative product. The setting of the question is very unclear.